# Python - How to fill string value with the modal value for the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like the below.  I want to be able to be able to populate the missing text with what is normal for the group.    I have tried using ffil but this doesn't help the ones that are blank at the start, and bfil similarly for the end.  How can I do this?

```
Group  Name
1      Annie
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      David
1      NaN
2      Bertha
3      Chris
4      NaN
```

Desired Output:

```
Group  Name
    1      Annie
    2      Bertha
    3      Chris
    4      David
    1      Annie
    2      Bertha
    3      Chris
    4      David
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` to create a modal mapping by group:

```
from collections import Counter

s = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])\
      .groupby('Group')['Name']\
      .apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common()[0][0])

df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna(df['Group'].map(s))

print(df)

   Group    Name
0      1   Annie
1      2  Bertha
2      3   Chris
3      4   David
4      1   Annie
5      2  Bertha
6      3   Chris
7      4   David
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` and `head`:

```
s = df.groupby('Group')['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1)).reset_index(-1)['level_1']
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna(df['Group'].map(s))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Group    Name
0      1   Annie
1      2  Bertha
2      3   Chris
3      4   David
4      1   Annie
5      2  Bertha
6      3   Chris
7      4   David
```